# Unknown command dumpdata

Tags: django

I want to dump data from db to file in view. But I have some problems. When I call command:

```
call_command('dumpdata')
```

I receive data on console, but I don`t know how to save it to file. Command

```
call_command('dumpdata > backup.json')
```

gives me in result

> Unknown command: 'dumpdata > backup.json' error.

```
    file = open(backup_name, 'w')
    file.write(call_command('dumpdata'))
    file.close()
```

also don`t work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call_command` does not accept [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29) commands, only [django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#available-commands) ones.

Instead use this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('backup.json', 'w')
call_command('dumpdata')
```

Comment: Good practice is to close the open file and set `sys.stdout` back to default.